# Jquery get name value of a button

Tags: jquery, button

I have a button like this:

```
<button class="language-select selected" type="button" name="en-gb"></button>
```

How can I get the `"en-gb"` name value in jQuery? I want to add an on-click event handler on that button.

Comment: In your click button event   alert($(this).attr("name"));

Comment: Thanks Jules It work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this selector:

```
$('button[name="en-gb"]')
```

For example,

```js
$('button[name="en-gb"]').click(
    function () {
        alert('Hello world!');
    }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="language-select selected" type="button" name="en-gb"></button>
```

Comment: Hello Ed! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @DaveManuel glad to help! If it solved your problem, please accept it by clicking the check mark.